# I need to open an image from android device, then I have to resize it to make it smaller, and finally upload it to firebase storage

Tags: android, firebase, upload, resize

I am creating an Android App that will allow users to upload images to Firebase Storage, but my problem is that modern devices take very large sized images and take a long time to upload, so I want to be able to resize images to make them smaller before uploading them to Firebase Storage.  Right now I am only able to upload images full size.

Comment: So what have you tried to do to resize the image?  What problems are you having?

Answer (score 1):

if i well understand your question you need to follow this tutorial in the following link
[How to Upload Images to Firebase from an Android App](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/image-upload-to-firebase-in-android-application--cms-29934).
and  to resize your image follow this [Resize an image in android to a given width](https://coderwall.com/p/wzinww/resize-an-image-in-android-to-a-given-width)

Comment: if this response helped you please validate it